# Clip path on d3 area not working in React.js

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg, clip-path

I have the following in a graph component in react:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);       

    this.state = {
        activeIndex: 9
    };

    this.margin = {
        top: 10,
        bottom: 15,
        h: 5
    }

    this.columnLines = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
    this.rowLines = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

    this.declareGraphFunctions();
}

declareGraphFunctions() {
    this.x = d3.scaleLinear() 
        .range([0,this.props.width-(2*this.margin.h)]) 
        .domain(d3.extent(this.props.data, (dataPoint, index) => index))
        .bind(this);

    this.yScaled = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([this.props.height*6.5/8-(this.margin.bottom), 0])
        .domain(d3.extent(this.props.data, (dataPoint) => dataPoint.amount))
        .bind(this);

    this.displacementY = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([this.props.height-(this.margin.bottom), 0])
        .domain(d3.extent(this.props.data, (dataPoint) => dataPoint.amount))(0) - this.yScaled(0);

    this.y = ((value) => this.yScaled(value) + this.displacementY).bind(this);

    this.line = d3.line()
        .x((dataPoint,index) => this.x(index))
        .y((dataPoint) => this.y(dataPoint.amount))
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
        .bind(this);

    this.area = d3.area()
        .x((dataPoint, index) => this.x(index))
        .y0(this.props.height-this.margin.bottom)
        .y1((dataPoint) => this.y(dataPoint.amount))
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
        .bind(this);
}

componentWillReceiveProps () {
    this.declareGraphFunctions();
}
```

And a part of the render function:

```
render() {
    return (
        <svg key={`graphsvg${this.props.width}${this.props.height}${this.state.activeIndex}`} width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} onMouseMove={this.handleHover.bind(this)}>
            <g transform={`translate(${this.margin.h},${this.margin.top})`}>
                <defs>
                    <clipPath id="clip">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width={this.x(this.state.activeIndex)} height={this.props.height}/>
                    </clipPath>
                </defs>

                <path className="graph-area" d={this.area(this.props.data)} clipPath="url(#clip)"/>
            </g>
        </svg>);
}
```

The rest of the graph functions render fine, and I have checked that the clipping rectangle is sized and resized correctly based on the component props. But the problem is that clipping is not applied to the graph area. Why is this?